# How to fix kendo header not displaying header content

Tags: asp.net, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Working with a kendo grid and have a several different columns with header text for each. I am trying to display "Datasheet" in the header cell for this columns but it's not showing. Not sure if I am writing this incorrectly or missing something entirely. Any help on how to get the header text to display is appreciated.

```
columns.Bound(a => a.ProductRoot.Name).ClientTemplate(
  "<a href='" + Url.Action("ProductDetails", "ProductCategories",
  new { productName = "#= ProductRoot.Name #", productType = ProductTypeEnum.SmallSignalBipolarTransistor }) + "'>#= ProductRoot.Name # </a>"
  ).Title("Product").HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "product-column-standard" }).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { @class = "product-column-standard" });


columns.Bound(a => a.ProductBuyLink).ClientTemplate(
  "<a href='" + "#= ProductDataSheetLink #" + "' target=blank>" + "<img title='Download' alt='Download Dataheet' src='../../images/pdf.gif'/></a>"
  ).Title("Datasheet").HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "product-column-standard" }).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { @class = "product-column-standard" });


columns.Bound(a => a.ProductRoot.ProductConfigurationType).Title("Configuration").HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "product-column-standard" }).HeaderHtmlAttributes(new { @class = "product-column-standard" });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **.HeaderTemplate("???");** instead

Here is how: https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/headertemplate